# Acrobat Error weblink.api

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I am getting the error as shown in the enclosed screenshot.

[image]

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: You might try following the suggestion given right there in the error message...

Comment: This error is a generic Windows error indicating a system configuration problem, so I would agree with Jeff, you need to contact your system Administrator.